# LibGDX: Can't manage to render a TiledMap with viewport

Tags: java, android, libgdx, rendering, tiled

**Hello :)**

Recently I have started programming in LibGDX. Now im 4 days stuck in rendering TiledMap on Viewport. I cant figure it out, but i know it is possible. Here is how the testing TiledMap looks:

[Testing tiled map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwD65.png)

How the game looks now ( no tiles showing ):

[The PlayScreen now (No tiles showing) Screen is blue becouse of ClearColor code down below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8D4F.png)

And here is my code in PlayScreen:

```
    public class PlayScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor{
    MainGame game;

    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Viewport gamePort;

    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;


    public PlayScreen(MainGame game) {
        this.game = game;

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        gamePort = new StretchViewport(MainGame.V_WIDTH / MainGame.PPM,
                MainGame.V_HEIGHT / MainGame.PPM, camera);
        renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(LevelManager.tiledMap,
                1/ MainGame.PPM);
        camera.position.set(gamePort.getWorldWidth() / 2, gamePort.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    public void update(float delta){
        camera.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        update(delta);

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor((float)66/255, (float)66/255, (float)255/255, 0f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        renderer.setView(camera);
        renderer.render();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        gamePort.update(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The LevelManager.tiledMap gets loaded in create method in MainGame class, so I load it just fine, but it doesnt show on the screen. It does when i dont use the Viewport.

Thank you all for future help :)

Comment: If your constants in MainGame are integers, cast them to floats in your viewport constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I fount that problem out, it was becouse PPM ( Pixels per meter ) in MainGame class, have been in format **Integer** and it has to be **Float**, otherwise the map won't render becouse of division problems in scaling.